# Select rows from table A where ID doesn't exists on table B or if exists, select only if is more than 3 months old

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables, one that stores the carts that the customers create by adding products in the front end of our ecommerce website, the other table (orders) is populated after the customer finishes checkout.

Some users have abandoned carts, so I want to check the carts table comparing it against the orders table by two conditions:

- If user has a cart entry and no orders entries of his own, then select that cart
- If user has a cart entry and some order entries, but user has no orders in the last three months and the cart is newer than three months, then select that cart

**Table carts**

```
cart_id   user_id      modified_on
5477        1125    2022-01-04 15:31:31
5476        2998    2022-01-04 14:34:31
5474        1305    2022-01-03 21:52:57
5473        986     2022-01-03 13:13:12
5471        3040    2022-01-03 01:32:28
```

**Table orders**

```
order_id    user_id    created_on
44           927      2018-11-23 00:26:43
46           932      2018-11-26 14:36:28
47           945      2018-11-26 15:35:34
48           948      2018-11-27 21:33:37
53           945      2018-12-02 18:20:55
```

So far I have come with this query nut I know it's wrong

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `vmc`.`user_id`,
    `vmo`.`order_id`,
    `vmc`.`created_on` AS `Order Created On`,
    `vmc`.`modified_on` AS `Cart Last Modified`,
FROM `carts` `vmc`
LEFT JOIN `orders` `vmo`
   ON `vmc`.`user_id` = `vmo`.`user_id`
WHERE `vmo`.`order_id` IS NULL 
    OR (`vmo`.`created_on` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND `vmc`.`cart_id` <> NULL)
ORDER BY `vmc`.`modified_on` DESC
```

Comment: So, it seems like you want carts where a user is having a MAX(orderdate) that is null or < 3 months ago? (left join to a `max(date) from orders group by userid` and seek where the maxd is null or old?)

Comment: Split it into two queries -- one for the rows that don't exist, the other where the last order is more than 3 months ago.

Comment: Then combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: `AND vmc.cart_id <> NULL` - why might the cart id be null (not that this is how you compare a null; using `<>` will kill your predicate, and is probably the main reason why you say "it's wrong" but I'm more keen to know what the thought process is..)? it's the PK of carts?

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should give you what you want:

```sql
SELECT
    `carts`.`user_id`,
    `sq2`.`order_id`,
    `sq2`.`last_order_date` AS `Last Order Date`,
    `carts`.`cart_id`,
    `carts`.`modified_on` AS `Cart Last Modified`
FROM `carts`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `user_id`, `order_id`, `sq1`.`last_order_date`
    FROM `orders` INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT `user_id`, MAX(`created_on`) as `last_order_date`
        FROM `orders`
        GROUP BY `order_id`
        ) `sq1` ON `orders`.`user_id` = `sq1`.`user_id`
) `sq2` ON `carts`.`user_id` = `sq2`.`user_id`
WHERE `sq2`.`order_id` IS NULL OR `sq2`.`last_order_date` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
ORDER BY `carts`.`modified_on` DESC
```

The subquery with alias `sq1` produces a relation of each unique `user_id` in the `orders` table with the maximum `created_on` date (aliased as `last_order_date`) for that `user_id`. The subquery with alias `sq2` does an inner join of the previous query with the `orders` table so that we can also get the `order_id` column associated with that maximum `created_on` row for each `user_id`. Finally, we do a left join of the `carts` table with the `sq2` table and apply our conditions.